# R programming - How to find out what Dim1 and Dim2 are in a Principal Component Analysis for K means

Tags: r, statistics, k-means

I have a dataset that looks like this. Multiple variables for each row [after being standardized].
[image]

Following code from another site, I am able to produce the viz for k means.

```
library(factoextra)
distance <- get_dist(d_top50summary)
fviz_dist(distance, 
gradient = list(low = "#00AFBB", mid = "white", high = "#FC4E07"))
k2 <- kmeans(d_top50summary, 
centers = 2, nstart = 25)
k2
fviz_cluster(k2, data = d_top50summary)
prcomp(d_top50summary)
```

Which results in this viz.
[image]

Question: How can I know what are the two most important variables used here?
Edit: Added prcomp line of code as per below comment from dcarlson and below screenshot.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: First delete the picture of your data. Second, post the results of `dput(d_top50summary)` so that we can replicate your analysis. Third, identify the packages you loaded with `library()` so we know where your functions come from. You can probably get your answer using `prcomp(d_top50summary).

Comment: hi, the data is from my own site so that's ok. I'm not sure what dput does. I edited the post to include the library factoextra and posted a screenshot with the prcomp command line you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: The `dput` function prints out a data frame in a plain text format that can be easily copy/pasted to R. It is the standard way of providing your data on stackoverflow. See `?dput` or `help(dput)`for details. Your output from `prcomp()` shows that all of your variables contribute equally to the first dimension but `timeonpage` is negatively associated with the other variables. Cluster 1 has lower values and Cluster 2 has higher values. For the second dimension `pageviewstotal` and `pagevaluetotal` dominate with lower values having positive values on the dimension.